# mysql update table set column3 where table1.column1 like concat ('%',table2.column2,'%')

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I saw recently (can't find it now) this syntax:
    ... LIKE CONCAT('%',col1,'%')

It is working for Selects but for update, it affects 0 rows
this is my query:

```
update locations set email = (
    select col2 from vendoremail 
    where locations.city LIKE CONCAT('%',col1,'%') 
    AND locations.zip LIKE CONCAT('%',col1,'%')
)
```

here is a sample of col1 :
"455 N Cherokee St: Muskogee, OK 74403"
without the quotes

I hope I have given enough data to elicit an answer or two - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards. You want to put the city and zip into the pattern.

```
update locations set email = (
    select col2 from vendoremail 
    where col1 LIKE CONCAT('%', locations.city, '%', locations.zip, '%')
)
```

However, this may not always work properly. If you have two vendors in the same city+zip, the subquery will return 2 emails, but when you use a subquery as a value it has to return only 1 row. You can add `LIMIT 1` to the subquery to prevent an error when this happens. But it will be selecting one of the vendors unpredictably -- maybe you should come up with a more reliable way to match the tables.

Comment: worked just fine for my case of 73 vendors and none with the same city,zip combo.  1 up and accepted answer - thank you!

Comment: One of these days you'll get a second vendor in the same city, and BOOM!

Answer (score 0):

If col1 is = "455 N Cherokee St: Muskogee, OK 74403"

i think location.city is = Muskogee and locations.zip is = 74403

then the query should be

```
update locations 
set email = (
select col2 from vendoremail 
where  col1   LIKE CONCAT('%',locations.city,'%') 
AND col1   locations.zip LIKE CONCAT('%',locations.zip,'%')
)
```